# How stack is used in C++

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I try to understand memory management during execution of C++ program. I know that when a function is called a function frame is placed on the stack. It consists of all local variables of that function. I also know that stack is a data structure that is organized the way that only data on the top is accessible . So why any local variables are accessible in all lines inside that function? Let's consider this example:

```
void function(int a, int b){ //Stack frame of function is placed on stack
a++; //variable a can be incremented
b++; //variable b can be incremented
a++; //variable a can be incremented again
}
```

So let's say stack is organized that way after a first line of the code:

```
Variable a 
----------
Variable b
----------
(...)
```

So I assume that I can access variable on the second line of the function because it is on the top of the stack, but how can I access to variable b next?
I think of it like variable a was pulled out the stack so variable b can be reached. But why can I reach variable a in the next line of the code? It was pulled out of the stack in the previous step.

Comment: "I also know that stack is a data structure that is organized the way that only data on the top is accessible" that is wrong, a stack is a data structure that lets you add or remove elements only at the top.

Comment: @tobi303: That depends on what kind of stack we're talking about. A true stack machine can only access the values at the top of the stack. It's just that modern processor architectures are not stack machines.

Comment: Uh, that's... What makes you think that? The stack is (often) only used to pass the parameters to the function. If you look at the generated assembly code, one of the first things that happens is that the values are moved from the stack into CPU registers. Also you can access any value on the stack at any time.

Comment: @UnholySheep: The stack is definitely used to hold also local variables, unless you have only a couple of them (and you don't get their address): declare a local `int x[1000]` and that will be on the stack.

Comment: The most important thing to understand is that "the stack" is an *implementation detail*. C++ does not require a stack at all for function call frames, it just happens that popular implementations emit code that works that way. Trying to derive C++ semantics from facts about the stack is therefore pointless because it's backwards: *nothing* about the stack enforces or imposes any requirements on the way the code works.

Comment: @rodrigo correct, but I was specifically referring to function parameters only. (I realize I worded it very poorly)

Comment: Many impelmentaion make assign some_base_register = StackPointer, for example call it BP then use addressinng BP+offset for arguments and BP-offset for locals. So a,b,c, can be accessed not by pop from stack

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up levels of granularity with the above example.

The call stack of a program doesn't store variables, it stores *call frames*. Variables are subobjects within a call frame (making up most of the data there). Your belief that "only data on the top is accessible" is correct, but the single object on top of the stack is the whole frame, not the most recent variable, and it contains all of the variables of the current call as its subfields. Since that one object is visible in its entirety, so are all of those fields, and therefore so are all of the current call's local variables.

The statement "only data on the top is accessible" holds, because while a function is being called, the *calling* frame is not visible, and neither are any of its variables. Again, all of those variables are just subfields of one object, which is the previous frame. When the current frame is popped, all of them simultaneously become visible again as the single top object becomes visible as a whole.

None of this has anything much to do with memory management. "The stack", as used to refer to memory, means something completely outside the scope of the C++ language, but nested function calls form a data structure that *works like* a "pure" stack, regardless of how the memory is provided by the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The standards that define C and C++ do not define "the stack" or "the heap". It is common for implementations that compile to programs for physical hardware to use the stack for activation frames and local variables, and to use the heap for dynamic allocation. However, this is not at all required (and thus not guaranteed) by the relevant standards.

With that out of the way, your question does not mention the platform you're interested in. As such, we don't know its capabilities, so it's a bit meaningless to discuss how variables that are not directly on top of the stack are accessed.

However, we can consider the example of how popular implementations of C for x86 handle this: at the beginning of a function (the "prologue" of the function), the frame size is simply <s>added to</s> subtracted from the stack pointer, after which local variables are accessed through indirect addressing relative to the frame (either the stack pointer or the base base pointer). At the end of the function (the "epilogue" of the function), the stack pointer is restored to point at the return address. Typically, a modern x86 compiler does not `push` or `pop` to "allocate" or access local variables.

Answer (score 1):

To see how the stack is used, compile the code to assemble. You can do this with g++ using `g++ -S main.c`.

You can then see what the stack is doing.

Eg `pushq %rbp` moves the location of the stack pointer, and `movl  $1, -12(%rbp)` moves a value (in this case, the value 1) into the memory location 12 bytes behind the top of the stack, and `movl  -4(%rbp), %eax` moves a value from 4 bytes behind the stack into the `eax` register.